# In kotlin co-routines, how to scope data to a 'request path' (example with MDC)?

Tags: android, kotlin

MDC was an amazing thing for logging and we still use this server-side in java with async programming.  Example for context

- Filter that sets a request id MDC.put("requestId", UUID.generate());
- controller invoked
- invokes service method
- invokes remotemethod (returns CompletableFuture)
- invokes function to be called after remotemethod returns (on another thread most likely)
- invokes more methods

No matter where in the world a developer adds log.info("some message") in the [webpieces project](https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces) or Twitter's finatra project, the requestId is logged because the logback.xml (or log4j 1 or 2 as well) has the pattern %X{requestId}.   This makes it so developers never forget to add request ID.  for example, log.info("some message") shows up in the logs like so

```
2023-07-21 12:43:49.681 INFO [myRequestIdHere] org.webpieces.asyncserver.impl.AsyncServerImpl
some message
```

Notice, they just logged 'some message' and myRequestIdHere shows up magically.  We use this for userId, customerId, requestId and a few pieces actually.

In old school sync programming, ThreadLocal is used which breaks in async.  Twitter has their own Future and webpieces subclasses CompletableFuture(which they forgot to pass through this context) and [created XFuture](https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces/blob/master/core/core-future/src/main/java/org/webpieces/util/futures/XFuture.java) which passes through this context.

In using co-routines, how can one do a filter at the top (or in android we are doing a platform click listener wrapping any dev who adds a listener so each click gets a request id and we pop an error saying encountered bug, requestId:xxxx and every log magicaly has requestId for that request context).

**This needs to work through suspend functions and regular not suspend functions** as a developer can call log.info() from anywhere

One of our developers pointed at [compositionlocal](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal) as coroutins context only seems to exist in the context of suspend functions :(

OR is there some way to get the context from a NOT suspend function.  After all, they must be storing is in some ThreadLocal to pass it down until the next co-routine at which point they can copy the state along with the next co-routine to be run later on response.  (I know they have to copy as if they don't, you can corrupt that state causing issues as co-routines is essentially just a fancy GREAT way of writing promises/future logic in a readable fashion).

thanks,
Dean

coroutine contexts but it didn't work so still researching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of what you said is correct. We can't easily use `ThreadLocal` with coroutines, because they often switch threads. Standard replacement for thread locals is storing the data in the coroutine context which is passed with the coroutine. However, as you pointed out, we don't have access to the context if not running inside a coroutine.

No, there is no way to access a coroutine context outside the suspend function. Context is not stored in a `ThreadLocal` - it is passed directly as a param to every suspend function. Each suspend function has a "hidden" continuation param and this is where the context is stored. Non-suspend functions don't receive a continuation, so there is no way to access the context from them.

I think probably the easiest way to access the data from both suspending and non-suspending context is by using `ThreadLocal`, but creating a hook for coroutines to restore this thread local value when resuming. As a matter of fact, coroutines provide such a hook already. We can add a hook for a given `ThreadLocal` by using the [asContextElement()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/as-context-element.html) extension:

```kotlin
private val variable = ThreadLocal<String>()

suspend fun main(): Unit = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    launch(variable.asContextElement("foo")) {
        repeat(5) {
            launch {
                println("foo: ${Thread.currentThread().name}: ${variable.get()}")
            }
        }
    }
    launch(variable.asContextElement("bar")) {
        repeat(5) {
            launch {
                println("bar: ${Thread.currentThread().name}: ${variable.get()}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample result:

```
bar: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1: bar
foo: DefaultDispatcher-worker-3: foo
foo: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2: foo
bar: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1: bar
foo: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2: foo
bar: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1: bar
foo: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2: foo
bar: DefaultDispatcher-worker-4: bar
foo: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1: foo
bar: DefaultDispatcher-worker-3: bar
```

In this example we run two concurrent "requests": `foo` and `bar`, each of them having a different value for the `variable`. Both requests share same threads, but the value of `variable` is always correctly matching the request.

If using this specifically for MDC and slf4j, please note coroutines provide support for it already: [MDCContext](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-slf4j/kotlinx.coroutines.slf4j/-m-d-c-context/). I believe underneath it uses a similar technique as above.

Please be careful when using scopes to launch new coroutines, e.g. `lifecycleScope.launch {}`. Coroutines started by explicitly providing a scope are not considered children of the current coroutine, they are separate execution flows and as such, they won't pass your stored value correctly. You would have to reinitialize the hook, e.g.:

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch(variable.asContextElement()) { ... }
```

Comment: WOW!!! thankyou @broot   (I was thinking there has to be someway to snapshot and the underyling logging can grab from threadlocal).... definitely going to try this!!

Comment: is that slf4j usable in android?  otherwise, we are just going to create our own basically BUT prefer re-using that MDC!!!!!!!!

Comment: I never used this `MDCContext` myself, but I assume it uses standard utils for slf4j. So as long as you use slf4j as your logging framework, I would expect it to work. I don't see anything similar for log4j or other frameworks, but as you said - it shouldn't be hard to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To complete [Broot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76737163/10138208), to solve the issue of using scopes to launch new coroutines we can simply create a new extension method that adds the threadLocal to the context of the new jobs, simply like this:

```
fun CoroutineScope.launchModified(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
): Job {
    return launch(this.coroutineContext + threadLocal.asContextElement() , start = start, block)
}
```