# MVI or MVVM can we create a single location for metrics, log and popup error?

Tags: android, mvvm

In android app, We want to have a setPlatformClickListener(listener, "eventname") that every developer is forced to use instead of setClickListener which has the following code.  Notice the POPUP_GENERIC_ERROR line....

```
//if you know metric systems, the global dimensions(tags) are OS, version, customerid, etc. etc. which are set in a global dimensions Map
Map<String, String> dimensions = Map.of("name", eventName);

String requestId = UUID.generate().toString();
Context.setMagic("RequestId", requestId);
//This above line is done more like the [solution in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76736918/in-kotlin-co-routines-how-to-scope-data-to-a-request-path-example-with-mdc)
try {
    metrics.increment("click.started", dimensions);
    //invoke the click listener of the developer...
    listener.invoke();
    metrics.increment("click.success", dimensions);
} catch(Exception e) {
    log.error("An error has occurred", e); //request id is logged
    dimensions.put("exception", e.getClass().getSimpleName());
    metrics.increment("click.failure", dimensions);
    POPUP_GENERIC_ERROR(requestId); //since EVERY log including the one above is logged with requestId, customer can give us request id
} finally {
    metrics.recordLatency("click.duration", dimensions, startTime);
    Context.remove("RequestId")
}
```

The popup generic error would pop up a dialog saying something like "You have encountered an error.  requestId: xxxxxx" with an 'ok' button for now.   The goal like we have done in countless GUI frameworks is to allow developers

1. to concentrate on success code and just have nullpointers and bugs throw to the top
2. prevent crashes since it seems android took a weird turn and any exception through to begin of thread can cause a crash (I am not sure why they did not opt for a simple let us help you pop a 'you have encountered a bug.  it may be a good idea to restart' instead giving the user the option

Is this possible in MVI or MVVM to do the above or is every single click listener going to have it's own error handling code (which will be a nightmare with over 200 click listeners).

Comment: You can have one location for handling that for the click listeners; although that will not be MVVM/MVI friendly

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible in MVI or MVVM to do the above or is every single
> click listener going to have it's own error handling code (which will
> be a nightmare with over 200 click listeners).

It's possible to unify the location of click listeners, as it's required to change the default behavior of the `onClick()` event; so you'd have custom click listener by using a wrapper which includes your custom code for metrics, log and popup error.

Something like:

Wrapper:

```
class OnClickListenerWrapper implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final View.OnClickListener listener;

    public OnClickListenerWrapper(View.OnClickListener l) {
        listener = l;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        try {
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "click.started");
            //invoke the click listener of the developer...
            listener.onClick(v);
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "click.ended");
            
            // ....... METRICS CODE

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "An error has occurred: " + e.getMessage()); 
            // ....... METRICS CODE

        } finally {
            // ....... METRICS CODE         
        }

    }

}
```

Now you have to use the `OnClickListenerWrapper` instead of `View.OnClickListener` to your views' click listeners.

Rough tests:

```
// 1st test (Normal behavior):

Button button1 = findViewById(...);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListenerWrapper(v -> {
    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "This is the Developer code for button click");
}));

// Output
//  D  click.started
//  D  This is the Developer code for button click
//  D  click.ended


// ------------------------------------------------------
// 2nd test (Error Handling)

Button button1 = findViewById(...);
Button button2 = null;
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListenerWrapper(v -> {
    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "This is the Developer code for button click");
    button2.getText(); // This raises NPE that is handled in the wrapper listener
}));

// Output
//  D  click.started
//  D  This is the Developer code for button click
//  D  An error has occurred: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.Button.getText()' on a null object reference
```

Now the listeners are unified to one place, but still it's not MVVM/MVI friendly because this assumes that the data layer (metrics) is now embedded into the custom listener where it has a direct access to the metrics central system.

This could be fixed somehow by passing metrics listener to the wrapper to either:

- Send these data back to the caller view (activity/fragment) >> MVI
- Send these data back to the caller view (activity/fragment) and then forward to the `ViewModel` >> MVVM.

Something like:

```
class Metrics {

    static Map<String, Integer> dimensions = new HashMap();

    public interface Listener {
        void start();

        void success();

        void failure();

        void recordLatency(int time);

    }

    static void start() {
        increment("click.started");
    }

    static void success() {
        increment("click.success");
    }

    static void failure() {
        increment("click.failure");
    }

    private static void increment(String key) {
        dimensions.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum);
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", key + " = " + dimensions.get(key));
    }

    static void recordLatency(int time) {
        String key = "click.duration";
        dimensions.put(key, time);
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", key + " = " + dimensions.get(key));
    }

}
```

You can use the `Listener` interface if you want to override every single method, but if the metrics system doesn't distinguish between different buttns' clicks; you can just use the abstract class `MetricsListener` implementation for simplicity:

The new wrapper listener:

```
class OnClickListenerWrapper implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final View.OnClickListener listener;

    private final Metrics.Listener metricsListener;

    public OnClickListenerWrapper(Metrics.Listener ml, View.OnClickListener l) {
        listener = l;
        metricsListener = ml;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        try {
            metricsListener.start();
            //invoke the click listener of the developer...
            listener.onClick(v);
            metricsListener.success();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "An error has occurred: " + e.getMessage()); //request id is logged
            metricsListener.failure();

        } finally {
            int startTime = 0; // rough time
            metricsListener.recordLatency(startTime);
        }

    }

}
```

Using the abstract class:

```
Button button2 = null;
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListenerWrapper(
        new Metrics.MetricsListener() {
            // Use the default implementation 
        },
        v -> {
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "This is the Developer code for button click");
            button2.getText();
        }));
```

Using the listener interface:

```
Button button2 = null;
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListenerWrapper(
        new Metrics.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void start() {
                // This should be through the ViewModel for MVVM
                Metrics.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void success() {
                // This should be through the ViewModel for MVVM
                Metrics.success();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure() {
                // This should be through the ViewModel for MVVM
                Metrics.failure();
            }

            @Override
            public void recordLatency(int time) {
                // This should be through the ViewModel for MVVM
                Metrics.recordLatency(time);
            }
        },

        v -> {
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "This is the Developer code for button click");
            button2.getText();
        }));
```

This is for MVI implementation, but you'd cascade that to the `ViewModel` for the MVVM.